# Unable to record/play audio [nsosstatuserrordomain 2003334207]

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

Recording & playing audio.
The audio file does not play when I store it on a path like:

```
audios/the_file_name.m4a
```

> Simple function I am using to get the documents directory to get directory

```
 func getDocumentsDirectory() ->NSURL{
        let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]

        return directoryURL
    }
```

> When I store file inside folders & subfolders. I am not able to play
>   files. It throws the error.

```
getDocumentsDirectory().URLByAppendingPathComponent("audios/audio_546152764271.m4a")
```

**`// This does not work & throw error  [nsosstatuserrordomain 2003334207]`**

> However when I record files in the documents directory only (no folders & sub folders) It works fine:

```
getDocumentsDirectory().URLByAppendingPathComponent("audio_546152764271.m4a")
```

**How can I play files that are inside folders & subfolders in documents directory?**

Comment: do not post multiple question on same topic..

Comment: Actually when The path of the file is something like
folder1/folder2/file Then it doesn't work.
On the other hand if I use just documents directory to store files, no inside "folders-folders" then no error is thrown

Comment: I've edited the question @EricD

Comment: @SunnyShah Sorry for multiple questions. I only posted one. I edited the question. Don't know how it get doubled.